# Kendo data source not working

Tags: kendo-ui

I am new with using the Kendo data source and so far it is not working. My page is extremely simple.

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>View Quote Lists</title>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
    <div>

    </div>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var query = "3";
        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/api/QuoteAPI?page=1",
                    dataType: "json"
                },
                requestEnd: function() {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(dataSource.data()))
                }
            }
        });
        dataSource.read();


    </script>

</body>
```

The server data set that is returned from the service is an object that looks like:
{
{"QuoteCount":13393,"CurrentPage":1,"Quotes":[{"QuoteID":"B0339420-52C1-4762-8F41-474BE601E872","QuoteNo":"00014857","QuoteDate":"2015.03.09","netgainID":"5BDF1655-CB35-4326-80E3-6DCA0CC00C8B","Qty":1.0,"SKU":"CC1512570","Product":"WELDMNT,ANTLER FRAME          ","Price":186.66,"Customer":"Grady Health Systems","repID":"{CA7A9606-8EAB-447E-934E-C52B4D8E06C6}","Rep":"Kirkland, Travis"},{"QuoteID":"B0339420-52C1-4762-8F41-474BE601E872","QuoteNo":"00014857","QuoteDate":"2015.03.09","netgainID":"8DBF5603-DAED-4DF8-89FD-1A172CA3589E","Qty":4.0,"SKU":"CC0900265","Product":"FRONT FLOOR PLATE (PR) 175 KIT","Price":28.95,"Customer":"Grady Health Systems","repID":"{CA7A9606-8EAB-447E-934E-C52B4D8E06C6}","Rep":"Kirkland, Travis"}......]

When I load the page is calls the web service and returns the data which I can see using Google tools. However the line dataSource.read() gives an error

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function     kendo.all.min.js:11

The requestEnd function is never called so I can't see the data even though it has been called.

Can someone tell me why this is not working. I have tried every variation of the docs that seem appropriate but this refuses to work.

Thanks,
Terry

Comment: You could consider rewording your question a bit more to make it appear less of a support-request and more of a programming-question. As it stands, there is a high chance of your question being closed as being off-topic.

Comment: I do understand your statement but I am hoping that someone can suggest a way of isolating what is happening from a javascript viewpoint and help find the issue. On the page I am looking at in the browser there are a dozen Related topics specific to Kendo that could be determined support as well. I have taken this to Telerik and so far the position is that it should work. I am hoping someone else has a better idea or I will just have to drop the use of the library I guess. Thanks for the response though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you move requestEnd out side of transport block and try? If it doesn't help create a Kendo Dojo to replicate the problem so that it's easier to fix it there.

Here is a [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/iYadu) with similar code that is working, except that I am using jsonp.

Comment: did you miss something. I cannot see your data in the comment.

Comment: Take a look above - I took your advice and put together a dojo although the data source will not run. I also displayed my return data structure in an answer so it would give me enough room to respond.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This pointed out the issue with the transport block and ultimately that enabled me to get something returning data. My mistake appears to be in trying to use the Telerik data source as a general data source for complex data. According to their tech support it really is only for flat data used on their controls and has no provisions for working with data "that the control has no use for" (in their words). Thanks again.